# How can I get sudo to log commands when password authentication terminates without passing or failing the password?

Tags: linux, sudo

With the default sudoers configuration in Ubuntu (and most other Linux distros), I can get the command logged in these cases:

- successful use of sudo
- user enters the wrong password 3 times (default `passwd_tries` value) leading to an unsuccessful use of sudo

But I cannot get the command logged in the case where the user invokes `sudo`, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> out of the password prompt. In this case, log messages generated include:

```
Aug 26 13:36:19 system sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
Aug 26 13:36:19 system sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [user]
```

Essentially, I want a `mail_always` but for logs